# Saving jfreechart as jpeg shows repeating legend

Tags: jfreechart

I have a created a Jfreechart and I'm trying to convert as an image.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chart");
frame.getContentPane().add(new ChartPanel(chart), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
createImage(chart);

//createImage method

public static void createImage(JFreeChart chart){
try{
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new    File("chartImage.jpeg"),chart,800,600);   
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: the problem is probably not specific to saving it as jpeg. Please add an example of your dataset or even better a [sscce](http://sscce.org)